# Creating new Google My Business/Places Review-Rating through API?

Tags: javascript, php, google-api

is it possible to create a new Rating through any Google API?

I got the following Information:

- Google Account (Username, Passwort)
- Customer ID
- Stars Count (1-5)
- Review Content (100-200 Chars)

Does anyone have an Idea how to make a new rating?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

It’s not possible to add/remove reviews or ratings; not with the GMB API or any API for that matter. They must be genuinely posted by users with their own Google accounts. If it were possible, anyone would be able to game the system.